# Scaling an image with WP7 Silverlight with no smoothing algorithm applied

Tags: silverlight, image, xaml, windows-phone-7, scaling

I have some images (32x32 .png) that I want to display in my Windows Phone 7 application.  Right, now, I am able to scale them, etc...  I was wondering if there was a way to scale them without any smoothing algorithms applied (so when I double the image size, it creates a blocky image look).

Right now in my XAML I have the following:

```
<Image Height="64" Width="64" Margin="12,0,9,0" Name="{Binding itemName}"
Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding imageName}" />
```

Where imageName is just a path to the .png images.  Is there a simple way to do this in just XAML, or should I be loading the image into a different format to play with it in the code (while keeping the transparency of the png).

Thanks in advance,
-Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres currently no way to do this in XAML. The only way to achieve a nearest neighbor scaling without any interpolation (smoothing) is the open source library WriteableBitmapEx.

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com

First load the PNG into a WriteableBitmap, then use the Resize extension method the WriteableBitmapEx provides. Use the NearestNeighbor as value for the last parameter of the method. Then assign the return value of the Resize method to the Source property of your Image control. 
You can wrap this functionality in an IValueConverter implementation so you can use it in XAML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Does this library support alpha transparency from .pngs?  (I see it mentions alpha at a quick glance)

Comment: Yes, it supports it and pays attention to the pre-multiplied alpha that is used for the WriteableBitmap.